# Содержимое одного div элемента по клику отображались в другом div элементе

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите пожалуйста! Есть изображения снизу. Надо что бы, при нажатии данные снизу отображались сверху. Из данных изображение(image) и текст(name). Никак не получается.
Такой html

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="hero" id="1">
        <div class="image"><img src="img/nilfgaard.jpg" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="name"><h1>Nilfgaard</h1></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Group-hero"> 
    <div class="hero" id="1">
        <div class="image"><img src="img/nilfgaard.jpg" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="name"><h1>Nilfgaard</h1></div>  
    </div>

    <div class="hero Redania" id="2">
        <div class="image"><img src="img/redania.jpg" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="name"><h1>Redania</h1></div>
    </div>

    <div class="hero Skellige" id="3">
        <div class="image"><img src="img/skellige.jpg" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="name"><h1>Skellige</h1></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ваши попытки? Или за вас просто надо написать?

Comment: Только начал изучать js, если можно подскажите хотя бы как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

1. выбрать всех героев

   ```js
   const heroes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.Group-hero .hero'))
   ```
2. на каждого из них навесить по бафу

   - [arr.forEach](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#foreach)
   - [item.addeventlistener('click', magicText)](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener)
3. - ,-

   ```
   const magicText = e =>
     document.getElementsByClassName('top')[0].appendChild(e.target)
   ```

   - [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Answer (score 0):

1. Определить контейнер, куда будут выводиться герои.

```js
    const showHeroWrap = document.querySelector('.top');
```

2. Определить всех героев.

```js
    const heroes = document.querySelectorAll('.hero');
```

3. Через цикл перебора `forEach`, для каждого элемента назначить событие `click`.

```js
    heroes.forEach(hero => hero.addEventListener('click', event => { ... }));
```

4. В теле функции события ты создаешь клон `.clonNode(true)` элемента по которому кликаешь, но, так как событие срабатывает и на внутренних элементах, целевой элемент события и итоговый клон может быть другой элемент (вложенный), ты используешь метод `.closest()`, этот метод будет идти вверх по дереву, пока не упрется в искомый по CSS-селектору элемент.

```js
   const clone = event.target.closest('.hero').cloneNode(true);
```

5. Очищение контейнера перед помещением туда клона, что бы не копить их там.

```js
    showHeroWrap.innerHTML = '';
```

6. Помещение `.append()` клонированного элемента `clone` в контейнер.

```js
   showHeroWrap.append(clone);
```

```js
const showHeroWrap = document.querySelector('.top');
const heroes = document.querySelectorAll('.hero');

heroes.forEach(hero => hero.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const clone = event.target.closest('.hero').cloneNode(true);
  
  showHeroWrap.innerHTML = '';
  showHeroWrap.append(clone);
}));
```

```css
.hero {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hero + .hero {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.Group-hero {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
}

.Group-hero .hero {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>

<div class="Group-hero"> 
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="image"><img src="img/nilfgaard.jpg" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="name"><h1>Nilfgaard</h1></div>  
    </div>

    <div class="hero Redania">
        <div class="image"><img src="img/redania.jpg" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="name"><h1>Redania</h1></div>
    </div>

    <div class="hero Skellige">
        <div class="image"><img src="img/skellige.jpg" alt=""> </div>
        <div class="name"><h1>Skellige</h1></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```